# A small glitch in the code trying to sort a single linked list :

Tags: c++

This is my code and actually all cases are working great , except when the first number in input list is less than the second like : 1243 , it gives : 2134 
i guess the problem in the `if (counter == SLS) {` statement

```
Element* Soreted_list(Element* LS) {
  if (isEmpty(LS))
    return LS;
  Element *counter, *temp, *SLS, *prev;
  SLS = LS;
  LS = LS->Next;
  SLS->Next = NULL;
  while (LS != NULL) {
    counter = SLS;
    while (counter->DATA < LS->DATA && counter->Next != NULL)
      counter = counter->Next;

    if (counter == SLS) {
      temp = LS->Next;
      LS->Next = SLS;
      SLS = LS;
      LS = temp;
    } else if (counter->Next == NULL && counter->DATA < LS->DATA) {
      counter->Next = LS;
      LS = LS->Next;
      counter = counter->Next;
      counter->Next = NULL;
    }

    else {
      prev = SLS;
      while (prev->Next != counter) {
        prev = prev->Next;
      }
      prev->Next = LS;
      LS = LS->Next;
      prev = prev->Next;
      prev->Next = counter;
    }
  }
  return SLS;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it certainly looks as if that section of the code is the problem. What did you *intend* it to do?

Comment: basically i get a linked list input , then i have to sort it increasingly , so this if statement will work if the first element is the minimum element , so that no element in the list is less than it an the counter will not move forward

Comment: Hint: in your inner loop `while (counter->DATA < LS->DATA ... )` allow `counter` to reach `nullptr` and update the logic in the body of your outer `while`. See how this simplifies your cases.